# Is this a router/switch/wirelessAP/modem?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point, modem, switch

When i bought the internet service from ISP I got a box through which I connect to Internet. It acts also as a wireless AP and I connect my several devices through it. On the other end it connects with the ISP infrastructure through cable technology (box from other ISP connects through DSL).

Is this box a router/switch/modem/wirelessAP and how can I tell?

Comment: What your isp calls it on their own homepage.

Comment: I think it calls it WLAN modem/router

Comment: What you describe is typically called a gateway.  It can have wireless capability but typically a modem/router combination is called a gateway

Answer (score 4):

It’s all of those. It has all of those functions in one box.

There’s not a single term to perfectly identify all the functionality in such a device, but if you tell people you have a “DOCSIS home gateway”, they’ll know it at least has a DOCSIS modem and NAT gateway router functionality, and they’ll probably assume it has the WI-Fi AP functionality and the LAN side switch, since those features are expected of multifunction home gateway routers.

Comment: Yes, it provides NAT router functionality for my home devices and also connects directly to Cable so has an integrated modem.

Answer (score 1):

This box is a router - routers often include more then 1 type of interface as there job is to push packets between interfaces.  Routers also often offer additional services like DHCP and DNS resolution as part of their function.

Although it performs the job of an AP, it is not an AP, as it does more then provide switch-type connectivity between a wired and wireless network.   (When a device which supports WIFI includes routing between networks, it would be called a WIFI router.

Calling it a cable-modem is likewise a bit of a stretch, because a modems job is to MODulate and dEModulate signals.  The addition of DHCP and multiple interfaces mean that this is not strictly a modem (but again, it contains one).   That said, a lot of companies initially bringing out early broadband "modems" were actually routers with only a broadband and WIFI interface, so this line has been blurred by marketers.

Comment: Would you say this is 1 single device (a router) with DOCSIS modem layer 2 functionality on one side and wirelessAP layer 2 functionality on other side?

Comment: It would be at least equally correct to simply call it a "cable router with built in WIFI"  if that helps.